# NFS - lockd: couldn't create RPC handle for 192.168.0.1

Tags: nfs

I'm seeing lots of messages in my `/var/log/messages` file like this:

```
Sep  2 17:36:47 hostname kernel: lockd: couldn't create RPC handle for 192.168.0.1
```

This server is NFS mounting a few directories from 192.168.0.1.

I have no idea where to start diagnosing this, and I'm pretty sure it's related to this [What does 'no locks available' mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/61594/what-does-no-locks-available-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you that they are directly related.  Once you resolve the issue with lockd / rpc.lockd, your Subversion lock issues will go away.

Can you verify that lockd / rpc.lockd started correctly on 192.168.0.1?  From your client, can you do 'rpcinfo -u 192.168.0.1 100021' ?

[This thread](http://www.archivum.info/linux.kernel/2005-12/05050/lockd:_couldn't_create_RPC_handle_for_(host)) has some useful information on lockd issues

Comment: # rpcinfo -u 192.168.0.1 100021 give this output:
rpcinfo: RPC: Timed out
program 100021 version 0 is not available

That means it's not running? How do I restart it?

Comment: Is there anything in dmesg on 192.168.0.1 re: lockd?  ie,

'lockd: new process, skipping host shutdown'
or
'lockd_up: makesock failed, error='

Also, can you check /proc/sys/sunrpc/rpc_lockd and see what value that is?

Comment: restarting the nfs server fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your NFS server is not running the rpc daemon. Try mounting your nfs with the "`-o nolock`" option. If that gets rid of your error messages, you have your reason. If there is only one client mounting that NFS share at a time, it should be safe enough to use the `nolock` option. This emulates the older NFS method of maintaining local locks only instead of remote locks.

Comment: restarting the NFS server solved it

Comment: was the rpc process killed?