# How can I configure NFS (v3) lockd to work across multiple IP addresses?

Tags: nfs

Consider the following short program, where `/nfsmount/merlin` is an NFS-mounted directory.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.nio.channels.*; 

public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        String evilFile = "/nfsmount/merlin/foobar"; 
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(evilFile, "rw"); 
        FileChannel chan = raf.getChannel(); 
        FileLock lock = chan.tryLock(); 
    } 
}
```

The NFS server has two IP addresses. When it is mounted over the first IP, the program above works fine. However, when it is mounted over the second IP, the program gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No locks available
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:91)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1095)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1154)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

A quick search leads to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/61594/what-does-no-locks-available-mean), which seems to indicate that there's something wrong with `lockd`. The fact that the program works on one IP would imply that `lockd` is only bound to one IP.

How can I configure it so that `lockd` works correctly over multiple IP's?

Comment: are you sure that there are no firewall involved? To find out to  which interface lockd bound:   netstat -tln | grep `rpcinfo -p | grep 100021 | grep tcp | awk '{ print $4 }' | uniq`

Comment: There is no firewall on the nfs server.  I will try the command you provided.  Thanks!